# Animated Gifs not showing in Cordova build of Meteor App

Tags: cordova, meteor

My browser version of the app works fine - I'm using the Giphy API to pull in gifs. The entire app is centered around gifs.

Is there anything special to get them working inside cordova?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to add access rules.

For example in `mobile-config.js` at root directory put:

```
App.accessRule('*');
```

http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/mobileconfigjs

Comment: I added one for giphy.com *.giphy.com/* -- I'll try '*' - but I read somewhere that animated gifs may not be supported out of the box in phonegap - and wondering if anyone else has experience that, and figured a work around..